# How make vb to show ( maximize ) another process (window)

Tags: vb.net

I have another program running and its process name is `met2.exe`. 
How can I get another program to maximize the `met2.exe` and keep it open in the start bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use [GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx)

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Integer
Sub ShowAppWindow()
    Try
        Dim localByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("met2")
        For Each p As Process In localByName
            ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 3) ' SW_MAXIMIZE
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' do something
    End Try
End Sub
```