# How would I switch to and maximize an outside application

Tags: vb.net

Someone may have already posted about this, but I am working on an application in VB.NET that requires me to switch to another open window and maximize it. I cannot for my life figure out a reliable way to do this (I gave up and called an autohotkey script, but even that broke). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I saw the forum post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456015/how-make-vb-to-show-maximize-another-process-window), but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make vb to show ( maximize ) another process (window)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456015/how-make-vb-to-show-maximize-another-process-window)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456015/how-make-vb-to-show-maximize-another-process-window) you already mentioned, you will notice that it contains following line:

`Dim localByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("met2")`

You need to replace "met2" string with exact name of process whose window you're trying to maximize. If you don't know the name of targeted process, do the following:

1. run the application you intend to maximize
2. open Task Manager
3. switch to "Processes" tab for complete list of running processes
4. pinpoint the process you're looking for (commonly the filename of running application)
5. use process name (commonly filename of the application) without extension as a friendly process name

For example, if you want to maximize running Notepad application using methodology explanied in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456015/how-make-vb-to-show-maximize-another-process-window) you will need to change following in existing code:

`Dim localByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")`

Comment: Please read complete reply, it's related to existing [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456015/how-make-vb-to-show-maximize-another-process-window).

Comment: Exactly but reiterating a post isn't what he was asking and you mentioned `if you want to maximize running Notepad application you will use` ... Which is wrong...that was what I was meaning...

Comment: Thanks, fixed it in text.